# Custom non-root package manager

Tags: centos7, yum

We have a software which is running on Centos 7 in a separate folder and under dedicated user without sudo privileges. Currently update process includes manual copying new zip files with new version and extracting them using bash scripts. It works fine, but we are interested in some additional features like version control, dependencies control and installation from repository. Yum is not an option since it doesn't support non-root installation. Could you please advice us some custom package manager with mentioned functionality and available for non-root users?

Answer (score 1):

Besides portable packaging formats, you can use other existing package managers which allow setting a root directory:

- `rpm --root dir`
- `dpkg --root=dir`

And if you need package resolution and similar features:

- `zypper --root dir`
- `dnf --installroot=dir`

Answer (score 0):

Portable packaging formats like AppImage or Flatpak can distribute complete applications in one container. I don't think they do interdependence between them very well though, they are quite self contained, and sometimes completely isolated.

Some languages can install modules local to the user, like pip for Python or CPAN for Perl. These require you to use their language, of course. They do have built in versioning systems with dependencies.

Checking out a working copy out of a version control system is a different way to deploy. Perhaps use git, clone for deployment, and pull updates from that same branch. Doesn't do dependencies though, would be easier if one repo contained the entire application.  And any scripts run would have to be done separately.

The existing method of extracting archives isn't bad necessarily. Of course automate it, so that it is deployed everywhere accurately.  If you build your scripting, versioning, and metadata around this archive, congratulations you have invented another packaging system. Nothing wrong with that, so long as it meets your needs and can be maintained.